# How to create an enterprise gallery app with blank signon url to enable IdP initiated flow?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How to define an AAD gallery app that uses IdP initiated login? Enterprise app wizard allows blank signon url. Gallery apps do not.

Comment: If my answer was helpful you could mark it as answer to help others. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you are absolutely right that  ***Enterprise app wizard allows blank signon URL***.

As seen on screen shot below:

[image]

And also true that ***gallery app do not allows blank signon URL***

Seen on Screen shot below

[image]

**Your Case**

As per your question, While you are going to registered gallery application would see the default IDP supports on each application. see the screen shot below

[image]

> But you can configure your IDP if the apps supports it. For this
>   application which I made a demo with also supports ***PASSWORD BASED
>   IDP***

**Configure your app**

You can [configure your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-federated-single-sign-on-gallery-applications) by following below steps:

> 1. Click on Getting started menu from left pane then
> 2. Click On Configure single sign-on (required)

See the picture below

[image]

Once you select configure now you can switch and modify your supported IDB between.
Like below:

[image]

You will get following menu to switch and can configure your SSO mode

[image]

> **Note:** 
>   **[To configure IDP SSO feature](https://docs.datadoghq.com/account_management/saml/azure/#configuration) an Azure AD Premium Subscription is**
>   **required to set this up!**

When you opted to integrate any gallery app you would get the proper implementation guide inside which I have shown on above screen shot. To examine demo that I have made for you could be refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/box-tutorial)